# Excel application crashes when opening macro enabled workbook

Tags: excel

When I am opening an excel workbook and open a macro excel file the application crashes, and when I reopen the application it asks me if I want to recover the file. Normal excel files open with no issues. But when I open any macro workbooks I get the following error messages:

[image]

I have restarted my computer and tried several different Excel files, all with the same results. has anyone got a work around for this?

My Excel trust centre macro settings are as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Two ways I've found success with in the past.

(1) Use Libre office to open it and resave as another file

(2) Rename the .xlsm to a .zip file, unzip the contents, then examine for broken xml structures. This is not trivial and I'd strongly recommend (1) first!

Comment: Hi, this is happening to all Macro files which I try to open. do you do this every time? this seems quite time consuming.